# Scope Logging in Application Insight

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, azure-application-insights

We have a .net core web api and we have used inbuild logger available in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging namespace.

We have integrated this logger with Application Insight.

I can see all the logs getting logged correctly. However, I am not able to see the logging information of scope

Below is my code:

```
var taskId = Guid.NewGuid();
            using (logger.BeginScope("Assigning Task {taskId}.",taskId))
            {
               logger.LogInformation("{taskId} is assigned",taskId);
            }
```

I can see this output where scope log information is matained in '{Original Format}'. However, structured logging is not working for that field :

[image]

I have below questions:

1. How does scope logging works in Application Insight?
2. Is this the only way to see the scope information?
3. Is there any way to see all the logs under one scope?
4. Why structured logging is not working for {Original Format}?

Comment: Depending on the logger, output of the scopes needs to be enabled explicitly.
For example, for the console logger you can configure in your `appsettings.json`
https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/835#issuecomment-389567342

Comment: Hi @Dusan, I have kept "IncludeScopes": true in appsettings.json. Is there anything else needs to be done to enable it for ApplicationInsight?

Comment: What version of the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet SDK are you using? Versions before 2.7.0-beta2 don't support scopes for App Insights. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger

Answer (score 2):

Scopes logging works nowadays in Application Insights (I'm using version 2.19.0). Instead of passing a format string + params to BeginScope() you should pass a dictionary of name-value pairs, e.g.

```
using (logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> 
         { { "TaskId" = taskId }, { "Action", "AssigningTask" } }))
{
    .. 
    logger.LogInformation("{taskId} is assigned", taskId);
    ...
}
```

Here putting the taskId in the inner log message is a bit redundant, of course.

Comment: In case if someone is still struggling to get it working; make sure you have the exact data type for key and value for the dictionary. It should be exactly `Dictionary<string, object>`